# jQuery trigger not working

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I'm trying to create a transition effect (from bottom to top) on a title, immediately after the page loads, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="portfolio-title-wrap animate">
    <div class="portfolio-title">Rooftop Garden </div>
    <div class="location">San Francisco, CA</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.animate {
background-color: #c00;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
right: 0;
}

.animate.move {
top: 0%;
margin-top: -700px;
}

.portfolio-title {
color: #F8941F;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.animate').trigger(
function() {
$(this).addClass("move");
});
```

**Demo:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Esgba/)

Comment: In your Fiddle, select jQuery from the drop-down on the left. And, apart from anything else, what did you expect this code to do, that it's not doing? Incidentally, [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) triggers an *event*, what you need is to use [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to work, you need to pass it an event type. This will then execute all handlers that were attached for the given event type. For example:

```
$('.animate').bind('move-event', function () { // handler will fire when 'move-event' is triggered
  $(this).addClass("move");        
});

$('.animate').trigger('move-event');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Esgba/)**.

​If you just want to add the class `move` on page load, no need to use `trigger` at all, just add the class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".animate").addClass("move"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations regarding the trigger function and for the answer! I was indeed just trying to add the `move` class to `animate`, after the page loads - but I was looking at this all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually triggering anything, you should pass [either an event name or an Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

```
.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] )
```

e.g.

```
  // Create a new jQuery.Event object with specified event properties.
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 64 });

  // trigger an artificial keydown event with keyCode 64
  jQuery("body").trigger( e );
```